# How to use angularGrid with Browserify?

Tags: grid, browserify, browserify-shim, angular-grid

I trying to implement [angular-gird](http://www.angulargrid.com/) using Browserify.

I used a configuration like this:

```
{
  "name": "Project",
  "description": "Description",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "repository": "...",
  "license": "License",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.3.15",
    "angular-ui-router": "0.2.14",
    "angular-grid": "1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "9.0.8",
    "browserify-shim": "3.8.5",
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
  },
  "browser": {
    "angular": "./client/app/common/angular-lib.js",
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "angular-ui-router": {
      "depends": "angular"
    },
    "angular-grid": {
      "depends": "angular"
    }
  }
}
```

But then I get the error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: require.config is not a function" (main.js).

Can someone help me? What is the best way to implement `angularGrid` with Browserify?